# NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Wed Jun 29 2022 10:19:00 GM" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe' - Angular

Tags: angular, date, pipeline

I don't know where in my code I am triggering this error but each time I click on an item it gives me this error :

[image: Error]

I think that this error means that I have to convert a string to a date but I am not sure.

This is my component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bookmark-history',
  templateUrl: './history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./history.component.scss']
})
export class HistoryComponent{

  Contents$:Observable<History[]>;
  ContentsInOrder$:Observable<Content[]>;
  Histories$=this.facade.Histories$;
  histo:History[];
  Date= new Date;
  

  showTrash = false;


  constructor(private historyService : HistoryService, private contentService : ContentService, private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, private facade:HistoryFacade, private dialogService:DialogService,
    private dialog:MatDialog) {
    this.Contents$=this.contentService.getContent();
    this.ContentsInOrder$=this.contentService.getContentInOrder();
    this.ContentsInOrder$ = this.ContentsInOrder$.pipe(map((result => result.sort((a,b) => b.points - a.points))))
    this.Histories$ = this.Histories$.pipe(map((rallies => rallies.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()))))
    this.facade.loadHistoryList();
    
    this.Histories$.subscribe(history => {
        this.histo = history as History[];
        
    }) 
   }

  onDeleteHistory(history:History){
    this.facade.deleteHistory(history);
  }

  onAddHistory(content:Content){

    const histo : History ={
      id : Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999),
      SNS:content.SNS,
      title:content.title,
      DMC:content.DMC,
      date : new Date(),
      showTrash : false
    }

    this.facade.addHistory(histo);
    this.facade.loadHistoryList();

  }

  onDeleteAll(){
    this.historyService.deleteAllHistory(this.histo);
  }

  @Output() click: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  onclick(){
    this.click.emit();
  }

  openDialog(){
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }

}

  @Pipe({ name: 'groupByDay' })
export class GroupByDayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private facade:HistoryFacade) {
     
   }

  Histories$=this.facade.Histories$;
  transform(items: any[]): any[] {
    // this gives an object with dates as keys
    const groups = items.reduce((groups, game) => {
      const date = game.date.toString().split('T')[0];
      if (!groups[date]) {
        groups[date] = [];
      }
      
      groups[date].push(game);
      return groups;
    }, {});

    // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
    const groupArrays = Object.entries(groups);

    console.log(groupArrays);
    return groupArrays;
    
  }
}
```

And this is my component template :

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" class="leftSide">
    <mat-tab label="Recent Document View">

        <div class="scroll">
            
            
            <div mat-subheader *ngIf="(Histories$ | async).length===0">The documents you visit will show here</div>
       
            <ng-container *ngIf="Histories$ | async">
                <ng-container
                  *ngFor="let group of Histories$ | async | groupByDay"
                >
                  <strong>{{ group[0] | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY' }}</strong>
                  <br />
                  <br />
              
                  <div *ngFor="let history of group[1]">
            <mat-list-item  class="historyClicking" (mouseover)="history.showTrash=true" (mouseout)="history.showTrash=false" (click)="onclick()">

                
                <div class="block">
                     
                <div matList>{{history.SNS}}</div>
                <div matList>{{history.title}}</div>
                <div matList>{{history.DMC}}</div>

                
                <div matLine class="onit" >
                    <button *ngIf="history.showTrash" mat-icon-button  (click)="onDeleteHistory(history)">
                    <mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <div *ngIf="!history.showTrash">{{history.date | date:"mediumTime"}}</div>
                </div>
 
        </div>
    
            </mat-list-item>
        
        </div>  
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

I think that the error is from this line in the template : `<div *ngFor="let history of group[1]">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`game.date` is supposed to be an `ISOstring` but here a `Date obj` is being passed which is turned to `toString()`. You may want to check if `game.date` is an `Date obj` and just parse it to `toISOstring()`.

```js
dateString = 'Wed Jun 20 2022 10:19:00 GMT';
newDate = new Date(dateString);

  if (newDate.constructor === Date) {
     isoDateString = newDate.toISOString();
     console.log(isoDateString);
  }
```

```js
  @Pipe({ name: 'groupByDay' })
export class GroupByDayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private facade:HistoryFacade) {
     
   }

  Histories$=this.facade.Histories$;
  transform(items: any[]): any[] {
    // this gives an object with dates as keys
    const groups = items.reduce((groups, game) => {

      let date: string;

      if (game.date.constructor === Date) {
         date = newDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
      } else {
         date = game.date.split('T')[0];
      }
       
      if (!groups[date]) {
        groups[date] = [];
      }
      
      groups[date].push(game);
      return groups;
    }, {});

    // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
    const groupArrays = Object.entries(groups);

    console.log(groupArrays);
    return groupArrays;
    
  }
}
```

Comment: I just have a question : Your code is functionning fine for GMT dates but not for GMT-400 dates (like the hours in the US), could you add something to your code that handles the dates with GMT-400 ? Because the dates added stop at the T of GMT but for dates that are longer it doesn't work

Comment: E.g `Wed Jun 20 2022 10:19:00 GMT-400` is still a valid Date, it works. https://jsfiddle.net/Nurech/23jo9vs6/

Comment: It does work from midnight to 7:59pm but at 8pm it doesn't work because the valid date for example : Wed Jun 20 2022 00:19:00 GMT-400 becomes : Wed Jun 21 2022 00:19:00 GMT. You can try it at 8pm USA time and you'll see that it creates elements for the day after

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I parse the date to make sure it's a valid date format? - @Picolo

If you're trying to ensure a date is valid, use the `getTime()` method and compare the `date.getTime() === date.getTime()`.

`getTime()` for an invalid date will return `NaN`. `NaN` isn't equal to itself.

```
dateIsValid(yourDateString: string): boolean {
    const testDate: Date = new Date(yourDateString);
    return testDate.getTime() === testDate.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
game.date.toString().split('T')[0]
```

This is your problem.  It's removing 'T' from the time zone portion of the date ("GMT") so the date can't parse.  It's not obvious to me why you need to split the date string, but I noticed that what's being parsed ends in 'GM'.

Comment: So how can I parse the date to make sure it's à valid date format ?

Comment: Looks like the pipe is designed to take dates from actual Date type, as well as strings.  Write unit tests against the pipe for both scenarios til u get the result you need.